# How to calculate $\Pr \left[ {X \ge YZ + \frac{1}{T}} \right]$ where all random variable are independently exponential distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How to calculate the probability $\Pr \left[ {X \ge YZ + \frac{1}{T}} \right]$  where all random variable X,Y,Z,T are exponential distributed and are all independent with parameters ${\lambda _x},{\lambda _y},{\lambda _z},{\lambda _t}$.
If it two variable then drawing the region of integration on paper is ok but I am not sure what kind of approach would be suitable for this case.

I do not think the close-form of this probability will exist so a result that use non-elementary function is also ok. Thank you !

Comment: There is no answer if there is no indepedence assumption.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the independent assumption

Comment: Writing out the integral is [straightforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3839780), a closed form in terms of the modified Bessel function $K_1$ and the exponential integral is
$$-2 \lambda_y \lambda_z \sqrt {\frac {\lambda_t} {\lambda_x}}
 e^{\lambda_y \lambda_z/\lambda_x}
 K_1(2 \sqrt {\lambda_x \lambda_t})
 \operatorname {Ei} \left( -\frac {\lambda_y \lambda_z} {\lambda_x} \right).$$

Comment: @Maxim Are you invoking the law of total probability for this problem :) ?